# Style Dojox Grid Row depending on data

Tags: css, dojo, grid

iam trying to style an Row inside an DojoX (1.2.3) Grid depending on values from the grid.

GridLayout:

```
var view1 = {
                noscroll: true,
                rows: [{
                    field: 'TASK_ID',
                    name: 'ID',
                    width: '80px',
                    get: this.getColor
                }, {
                    field: 'MENUPOINT',
                    name: 'Action',
                    width: '250px'
                }]
            };
```

getColor Function:

```
 getColor: function(inRowIndex) {
        console.log(inRowIndex);
        grid = dijit.byId('gridTaskCurrent');
            // if task_id = 1 style row with other background(?)
        },
```

And i have no idea how to get the task_id value from every row and set an style for
the row.. if someone has an good link or knows how to do.. that would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it by my self:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('gridTaskCurrent'), 'onStyleRow' , this, function(row) {
                   var item = grid.getItem(row.index);

                    if (item) {
                        var type = grid.store.getValue(item, "LOCKED", null);
                        if (type == 1) {
                            row.customStyles += "background-color:limegreen;";
                        }
                    }

                    grid.focus.styleRow(row);
                    grid.edit.styleRow(row);


                });
```