# Trying to Change Dojogrid Rowcolor based on Content

Tags: java, dojo

I have a function that generates a Dgrid and fills it with content which it receives from Javaside.

I tried to do dojo-css to handle this like here:
 [Style Dojox Grid Row depending on data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818872/style-dojox-grid-row-depending-on-data)

After this didn´t work I tried to work with Dojo.connect to change the color of the row when the grid is being built and filled. 
After that didn´t work I tried to use `dojo.on` or `dojo.aspect.after` but since I am a total Newbie in Dojo I have no clue where you can intersect in the code and do theses things.

with a code like so :

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr","dojo/dom-form", "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/json",'dgrid/Grid','dgrid/Selection',"dijit/registry","dojo/_base/declare","dojo/domReady!"],
        function(xhr,domForm,dom, array, json, grid, selection,registry, declare){
 ..... Here the grid and data is declared java function called
}.then(function(data, array, grid, selection,registry, declare){
  .....Here the dgrid is filled
}
```

Where/when should i use `Dojo.Connect` , `Dojo.on` or `Dojo.after`?
I´ve spent mutiple days trying to figure this out but the program either stops working or ignores my changes.

Answer (score 0):

The link you mention above is for dojox grid, which is different to dgrid. Here is the link to [css styling for dgrid](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/css-styling-of-dgrid/).
It won't answer your question though which is about changing a row color based on content. The way I do this is cell by cell, using a custom renderCell function.

Documentation on renderCell can be found [here](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.2.1/doc/components/core-components/Grid.md), and an example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/gamejunkie/4288890).

ps: a bit of caution. The learning curve for dojo 1.x is quite steep. When looking for documentation, make sure you get the latest possible (1.10). If you find a link which is about version 1.6 or less, be careful: many 1.6 and before features have been deprecated in version 1.7.